# Swift iOS Charts - Hide certain Bar Chart value labels

Tags: ios, swift, charts, bar-chart

I am using the 'Charts' framework for my iOS app using swift and I am using the Bar Chart on one of my VCs but it looks quite messy at the moment because it displays the value labels for every value, even if it's 0. I was wondering if it's possible to only show the labels if the value is above 0? I have been looking at other questions but I can't seem to find an answer for this. I know I can hide all of the labels using `chartData.setDrawValues(false)` however, I still want to display the values when they are above 0.

[image]

This is my current code to format the chart -

```
    barChart.highlightPerTapEnabled = false
    barChart.highlightPerDragEnabled = false
    barChart.leftAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = true
    barChart.leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    barChart.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
    barChart.xAxis.centerAxisLabelsEnabled = true
    barChart.xAxis.axisMinimum = 0
    barChart.xAxis.axisMaximum = 7
    barChart.xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = true
    barChart.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = true
    barChart.rightAxis.enabled = false
    barChart.leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0
```

I thought about doing something like this -

```
 for value in chartDataSet.entries {
    if value.y == 0 {
      chartDataSet.drawValuesEnabled = false
    }
    else {
      chartDataSet.drawValuesEnabled = true
    }
 }
```

but of course this doesn't work as it sets the boolean for the whole set.

Any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to provide your custom `IValueFormatter` to `BarChartData` as below,

```
public class XValueFormatter: NSObject, IValueFormatter {

    public func stringForValue(_ value: Double, entry: ChartDataEntry, dataSetIndex: Int, viewPortHandler: ViewPortHandler?) -> String {
        return value <= 0.0 ? "" : String(describing: value)
    }
}

let chartData = BarChartData(dataSet: yourSet)
chartData.setValueFormatter(XValueFormatter())
```

**Note:** `String(describing: value)` is just to provide a workable example. You can apply proper number formatter to convert `Double` into `String`.

Comment: Thanks this worked! Haven't really had much experience with IValueFormatter so will need to look into it a bit more to fully understand it

Answer (score 0):

```
 barChartView.data?.setDrawValues(false)
// to disable the data in the bars
```

[image]

[image]